# Using different Path to the same controller in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a yii-controller handling everything under

```
/controllername/list/type/{something}.
```

The same controller should be used under a different path

```
/admin/controllername/list/type/{something}
```

because some rights are set differently.

How can I use the same controller in both instances under Yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second url format should be a different module, you can set access control filter in controller or use RBAC for different user instead of changing url format.

About Yii module http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html

Authorization http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: So, it is not possible, to re-use the code from a different path? bummer.

Comment: If you want to re-use the code exetends the class but not this way. Or just put your common part into /protected/components/Controller.php. (This is Yii 1.1 code structure)